# Python wired index out of bound

Tags: python, algorithm

I was trying to create a volume weighted average price using python.
Here is my code:

```
vwap = []
for i in range(window, int(price_times_qty)):
    vol_total = 0
    vol_price = 0
    for j in range(window):
        vol_total = vol_total + lastqty[i-j]
        vol_price = vol_price + lastqty[i-j] * lastprice[i-j]
    vwap.append( vol_price / vol_total )
```

I believe my idea is right, but when I execute the code, I have the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-9-9724942aa7be>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/home/intern2/Desktop/VWAP/vwap-v1.py', wdir='/home/intern2/Desktop/VWAP')

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 586, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 48, in execfile
exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/home/intern2/Desktop/VWAP/vwap-v1.py", line 25, in <module>
vol_total = vol_total + lastqty[i-j]

IndexError: index out of bounds
```

I just have no idea why the error is index out of bound. When I check my code, I think the index is well within the bound.

Could anyone please help me with it?

Comment: Where is `lastqty` defined? And what is it defined as? clearly `i-j` is more than its length.

Comment: What is the index wired to?

Comment: Please define the values of `lastqty` and `lastprice`